Delay in Solana transaction
Yesterday I transferred my Solana tokens from the "Solana Cloud Mining" site to my Solflare asset wallet. More than 24 hours have passed and still nothing.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Unfortunately, it's highly likely that you have fallen victim to a scam site. These "cloud mining" sites often promise high returns on investments but end up stealing funds from unsuspecting users. In this case since Solana does not even support mining I think it's unlikely that you will receive any tokens.
